# Get each digit of a number

Tags: javascript, performance, built-in

What's the best way to get the Nth digit of a number in javascript?

For example, for `31415926`, the function will return 1 if `N=2`.

**EDIT**: And if possible, tu return directly a number, not a string.

**EDIT 2**: It is from left to right.

Comment: Convert to a string then use substr, like `(number+"").substr(1,1)` (first char for substr have index 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with that : `(''+number)[nth]` or `(''+number)[nth-1]` if one-based.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use:

```
function getNthDigit(number, n){
    return parseInt((""+number).charAt(n));
}
```

But if you don't want it to be in String form ever you could use:

```
function getNthDigit(number, n){
    var num = number,
        digits = 0;
    do{
        num /= 10;
        digits++;
    }while(num>=1);

    num = number / Math.pow(10, (digits - n));
    num -= num % 1;

    return (num % 10);
}
```

On second thought, just use the first option.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `charAt(n)` ?

Comment: @Mageek - Yes it should. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I didn't consider the fact that it was counting from the right. My bad!

Anyway, considering that the input is STILL a string, I'd use the same function, just with a little tweak.

Why don't you use the [CharAt function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)? I think is the best option, considering the risk of multi-byte strings!!!

EDIT: I forgot the example:

```
  var str = "1234567";
  var n = str.charAt(str.length-2); // n is "6"
```

Comment: The risk of multibyte strings ?